# Transposing posted multiple arrays into codeigniter's insert_batch style

Tags: arrays, forms, codeigniter, batch-file, multilingual

I am trying to create multi-lingual form with Codeigniter.

I have an POST array as:

```
Array
(
  [title] => Array
    (
        [en] => English Title
        [de] => German Title
    )

  [url] => Array
    (
        [en] => English URL
        [de] => German URL
    )
)
```

I want to convert this into codeigniter `insert_batch('tablename',$data)` format like:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [lang] => en
        [title] => English Title
        [url] => English URL
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
       [lang] => de  // Assuming user didn't fill `_de` labeled input fields.
       [title] => 
       [url] =>
    )
)
```

Data to be stored in db as:

```
|id|lang|    title      |    url      |
|--|----|---------------|-------------|
|  | en | English Title | English URL |
---------------------------------------
```

How can i achieve this? I need to transpose post array to `insert_batch`'s data array style. Above, `array[1]` contains only prefined `lang` as `de`. So `array[1]` is empty for me literally. So i also need to remove empty arrays from final `$data`.

Below, you will find view file.

```
<div id="tabs">
  <?php echo form_open('controller/post_target',array('name'=>'add_page')); ?>
  <ul>
    <?php foreach($lang_data as $r):?>
    <li><a href="#tab_<?=$r->lang;?>"><?=$r->name;?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>        
  </ul>

  <?php foreach($query_lang as $r):?>
  <div id="tab_<?=$r->lang;?>">
    <?php echo form_label('Page Title','title'); ?>
    <?php 
      $attr1 = array('name' => 'title[' . $r->lang . ']');
      echo form_input($attr1); 

      $attr2 = array(name' => 'url[' . $r->lang . ']');
      echo form_input($attr2); 
    ?>
  </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php echo form_submit('submit','Save'); ?>
  <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

Just for info, I scratched a few line as controller but I want to have a clean-coded controller about this. Also my version can't check it if array empty. :( Any advise for more professional way is welcomed.

```
if($this->input->post('submit'))
{
  $data = $this->input->post();
  unset($data['submit']); // SELF NOTE : IT should be easier way to do this   

  foreach ($data as $key => $value)
  {
    $counter = 0;
    foreach ($value as $key_inner => $value_inner)
    {
      if( ! isset($db_array[$counter])) $db_array[$counter] = array();
      //Above line enable us to use '+=' operand below in foreach loop

      $db_array[$counter] += array(
          'lang' => $key_inner,
          $key => $value_inner
      );          
      $counter ++;
    }
  }

  //echo '<pre>'; print_r($db_array); echo '</pre>' . '<br />';

  if($this->db->insert_batch('test',$db_array)) echo 'record saved';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create some functions to do that. Since the `lang` property has a special behavior (not the same as title or url), I think it would be best to define the languages in an array.

I create two functions below, the first one converts the input data to the format you need for batch insert and the second removes empty rows (`lang` should be ignored since it will be always set).

I would suggest to set $data manually with the fields you want to translate and not pass the entire `$_POST` values. You might add in the future other inputs which are not translated and I would suggest a white list mechanism with all inputs translated instead of blacklist (unset the submit button).

UPDATE
added $fields parameter as the list of fields which are translated

```
$data = prepare_data_for_insert($data, array('title', 'url'), array('en', 'de'));
var_dump($data);
$data = remove_empty_rows($data, array('lang'));
var_dump($data);

function prepare_data_for_insert($data, $fields, $langs) {
    $result = array();

    $i = 0;
    // foreach language defined
    foreach ($langs as $lang) {
        // set the languge
        $result[$i]['lang'] = $lang;
        // foreach field that we want to translate
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            // set the value for the current language
            $result[$i][$field] = $data[$field][$lang];
        }
        $i++;
    }

    return $result;
}

function remove_empty_rows($data, $ignore_fields = array()) {
    $result = array();

    // result
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $has_values = false;
        foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
            // check if the key is ignored
            if (in_array($key, $ignore_fields)) {
                continue;
            }

            // if a value was set
            if ($value != '') {
                // the array has values
                $has_values = true;
                // don't search for other values
                break;
            }
        }

        // if the array has values
        if ($has_values) {
            // save the row in the result
            $result[] = $item;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: it worked perfectly fine. I added function to model, then it works. Do you mind if I ask you more about whitelisting instead of unset['submitBuyyonName']. ?

Comment: The idea of using a white-list has some advantages for future cases where you might add new fields that are not `to translate` in the form (e.g. a checkbox marking the url active). Another aspect involves security: you need to extract the values you need from the submitted form and not save everything into the database. If you have any questions, feel free to ask

Comment: thanks fy help. Checkbox are exactly the reason of my yesterday's comment :) Maybe I should open a new question but basically, how should be basic function to white-list selected array elements, if you have time of course. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi. I updated the code and added a parameter `$fields` in the function `prepare_data_for_insert`. This parameter should contain an array with the fields that you want to translate, so other fields (like checkboxes or submit values) are ignored. That is what I meant by creating a white list with the fields you want to translate. I hope it helps

Comment: Works great. Thank you so much for your committed contribution @mazzucci.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can do similar:

```
$langs = array_keys($post["title"]);
$batch = array();
foreach ($langs as $lang) {
      $tmp = array();
      $tmp["title"] = $post["title"][$lang];
      $tmp["url"] = $post["url"][$lang];
      $batch[] = $tmp;
}
```

Not tested and doesn't check any errors in post-structure.

Comment: Thank you fy reply... mazzucci's way gave me more home feeling.